# ListBox does not display values when access project is launched using Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm very new to access.

I am trying to run an Access application connected with Sql Server database in Access 2010.

The only problem is, I have a list box that does not display anything.

When I open the Access file using Access 2007 however, the list box displays all data.

Are there any properties or configuration I need to change for list box to work normally on Access 2010?

Comment: Welll 2007 and 2010 are very different versions of access. you might be dealing with a few issues

Comment: The following is the code that gets the source:
 lstPaySheet.RowSource = "EXEC procFetchInputSheet " & CStr(txtInputSheetID.Value)
 Where,
lstPaySheet is the list box
procFetchInputSheet is the stored proc that gets all the data each rows
CStr(txtInputSheetID.Value is a parameter passed to the stored proc.

When I run the stored procedure on SQL Server Management Studio, it gives all the required rows. But when I run the Access application using Access 2010 none of the rows are displayed in the list box. The same application when I run it using Access 2007 the values are displayed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using an ODBC link to the SQL Server data?
If so, make a pass-through query that holds the `EXEC procFetchInputSheet` command.
Once you get that working, set `lstPaySheet.RowSource` to the name of the query.